# XSL to Parse and Re-order XML Nodes

Tags: xslt

I need assistance with creating a XSL stylesheet to parse data and re-order based on values within certain nodes. My original XML is being exported by a roster program in a undesirable structure which is causing issues when converting to JSON.

This is a Fire Department roster that will be converted into JSON to be processed by Station Status Boards. I'm looking to format the XML so that when converted into JSON each Station has a crew list. I've attempted to create a XSL without success. I have zero background in XSL (Fire Fighter).

Section of Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
    <Date>2019-05-07-07:00</Date>
    <Headers></Headers>
    <Records>
        <Record>
            <RscPayrollIDCh>12345678</RscPayrollIDCh>
            <RscEmployeeIDCh>12345678</RscEmployeeIDCh>
            <RscMasterNameCh>Smith, Mike A.</RscMasterNameCh>
            <InstitutionAbrvCh>SPL</InstitutionAbrvCh>
            <AgencyAbrvCh>SPFD</AgencyAbrvCh>
            <RegionAbrvCh>OPS</RegionAbrvCh>
            <StationAbrvCh>B19</StationAbrvCh>
            <PUnitAbrvCh>BAT19</PUnitAbrvCh>
            <PosJobAbrvCh>BC-S</PosJobAbrvCh>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <RscPayrollIDCh>12345</RscPayrollIDCh>
            <RscEmployeeIDCh>12345</RscEmployeeIDCh>
            <RscMasterNameCh>Smith, John A.</RscMasterNameCh>
            <InstitutionAbrvCh>SPL</InstitutionAbrvCh>
            <AgencyAbrvCh>SPFD</AgencyAbrvCh>
            <RegionAbrvCh>OPS</RegionAbrvCh>
            <StationAbrvCh>S15</StationAbrvCh>
            <PUnitAbrvCh>E15</PUnitAbrvCh>
            <PosJobAbrvCh>CAPT</PosJobAbrvCh>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <RscPayrollIDCh>123456</RscPayrollIDCh>
            <RscEmployeeIDCh>123456</RscEmployeeIDCh>
            <RscMasterNameCh>Smith, Bob R.</RscMasterNameCh>
            <InstitutionAbrvCh>SPL</InstitutionAbrvCh>
            <AgencyAbrvCh>SPFD</AgencyAbrvCh>
            <RegionAbrvCh>OPS</RegionAbrvCh>
            <StationAbrvCh>S15</StationAbrvCh>
            <PUnitAbrvCh>E15</PUnitAbrvCh>
            <PosJobAbrvCh>ENG</PosJobAbrvCh>
        </Record>
    </Records>
</Data>
```

I would like to format the XML so that it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
    <Date>2019-05-07-07:00</Date>
    <Headers></Headers>
    <Records>
        <Record>
            <StationAbrvCh>B19</StationAbrvCh>
                <RscMasterNameCh>Smith, Mike A.</RscMasterNameCh>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <StationAbrvCh>S15</StationAbrvCh>
                <RscMasterNameCh>Smith, John A.</RscMasterNameCh>
                <RscMasterNameCh>Smith, Bob R.</RscMasterNameCh>
        </Record>
    </Records>
```

I would like my roster to list each crew member  under the Station  they are assigned to for the day.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **XSLT 1.0**, *Muenchian grouping* is the best approach to achieve it as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:key name="groups" match="/Data/Records/Record" use="StationAbrvCh" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Data/Records">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', StationAbrvCh)[1])]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <StationAbrvCh><xsl:value-of select="StationAbrvCh" /></StationAbrvCh>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', StationAbrvCh)">
                    <RscMasterNameCh><xsl:value-of select="RscMasterNameCh" /></RscMasterNameCh>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See demo here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpM

Comment: This Worked! Thank You so much to everyone who responded back with an answer. I'll be further educating myself on XSL as I see myself using this again in the future.

Comment: @DGray: Glad it helped. You can close the question by accepting answer which worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using **XSLT 2.0** it is quite easy.

In the template maching `Records`, you should use `for-each-group`
selecting `Record` elements and grouping them by `StationAbrvCh`.

Within each group you should:

- Generate `StationAbrvCh` element, filled with the current grouping key
  (also `StationAbrvCh`).
- Run a `for-each` loop for the current group, copying to the output the
  current `RscMasterNameCh`.

The script should contain also the *identity template*.

Below you have an example script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Records">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="StationAbrvCh">
        <xsl:copy>
          <StationAbrvCh><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></StationAbrvCh>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:sequence select="RscMasterNameCh"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Maybe, to fully understand each detail of the above solution,
you should search the Web for description of `for-each-group`
and related functions (`current-grouping-key()` and `current-group`).

Comment: There is no need for the `for-each` with the nested `sequence`, you can just output `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/RscMasterNameCh"/>`. Or just use `<xsl:copy-of select="StationAbrvCh, current-group()/RscMasterNameCh"/>`as the sole contents of the `xsl:copy` inside the `for-each-group`.